# What is the difference between Mockito.mock(SomeClass) and the @Mock annotation?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mocking, mockito

What is the difference between `Mockito.mock(Class<T> classToMock)` method and the `@Mock` annotation?
Are they the same?

For Example, is this:

```
private TestClass test = Mockito.mock(TestClass.class);
```

the same as:

```
@Mock
private TestClass test;
```

Comment: There are pros and cons for each approach: https://mincong.io/2019/09/13/init-mock/

Answer (score 92, accepted):

They both achieve the same result. Using an annotation (`@Mock`) is usually considered "cleaner", as you don't fill up your code with boilerplate assignments that all look the same.

Note that in order to use the `@Mock` annotation, your test class should be annotated with `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` or contain a call to `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)` in its `@Before` method.

Comment: Don't forget about @InjectMocks

Comment: And don't forget about the mock names in the error messages.  So the two don't _quite_ achieve the same result.

Answer (score 13):

The difference is in the lines of code you need to write :) :) :)

Seriously though, using the annotations has the exact same effect as using the Mockito.mock.

To quote the documentation of `MockitoAnnotations` the use of annotations has the following benefits:

- Allows shorthand creation of objects required for testing.
- Minimizes repetitive mock creation code.
- Makes the test class more readable.
- Makes the verification error easier to read because field name is
  used to identify the mock.

The javadoc for `MockitoAnnotations` is [here](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/MockitoAnnotations.html)

Comment: I find it strange to say shorthand. Yes, it requires fewer characters, but it requires more lines.

Comment: In the context of software development shorthand I have always interpreted shorthand as meaning that I have to write less code :)

Comment: @RogerCSWernersson - you can put the annotation on the same line, annotations don't require a following newline.

Answer (score 8):

There are two significant advantages to using the annotation.

- A mock created with `@Mock` can be injected into the class you're testing, using the `@InjectMocks` annotation.  This is a powerful technique that can make testing significantly easier.  It just won't work with mocks created by the `mock` method.
- If you have any errors involving your mock, the name of the mock will appear in the message.  If you've used `@Mock`, then this name will just be the name of the field.  This makes it really easy to find the problem mock.

Of course, in addition to these two important advantages, most people find the `@Mock` notation much more readable, and it does cut down on the amount of code.  I see no reason not to use it.

Answer (score 6):

They both are considered same and achieve the same thing but I'd prefer the second one:

@Mock is an annotation which:

- Minimizes repetitive mock creation code.
- Makes the test class more readable.
- Allows shorthand creation of objects required for testing.

Answer (score 1):

The answer of the question is one big mistake.
We just solved some problems caused by Mockito.mock(Your.class) as a field.
We had few @Test methods. The 4th method was throwing an exception with 'thenThrow(ex)'. All of the @Test methods after it was failing and the reason was the exception thrown. They were sharing the mocked instance and the 'when' condition. After we changed from

```
TestClass testInstance = Mockito.mock(TestClass.class);
```

to

```
@Mock
TestClass testInstance;
```

everything started to work as expected. So Mockito.mock is creating a shared mock between the test methods, and @Mock does not.

Comment: This is incorrect. If you use `@Mock`, then you have to use `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)` in the `@Before`, which is equivalent to just writing `Mockito.mock(Some.class)` in the same `@Before` setup method. (then the mock is recreated before each test and the problem you described goes away)

Comment: it may go away but thats a main difference.

Comment: This is not true if you are using JUnit, it "creates a new instance of each test class before executing each test method" - https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-test-instance-lifecycle

Answer (score -3):

In Junit5, use

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
```